# HTML href onclick will not trigger javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I have been asked to update my question so here goes:

I have records in a database, some of which have wave file names attached.  I am looping through the database and wanting to write out the word "Play" in a column under a header named Audio File. When "Play" is clicked on, the audio player plays the file and turns the href word to "Pause". When my code loops through these records, it is assigning a separate ID to each href.  For me to call the function that starts the audio player, I need to send an audioControl ID (aControl) variable as well as the src source file (thissource) variable for the audio player - hence the & and " in the function call. When I use the onclick event in a button, it triggers the function.  However, when I click the href link (which is what I want instead of a button) nothing happens.  I am not sure which part of the code is messy, as I found the function code on the internet.  Thank-you in advance for any and all help.

No matter what I do, my href onclick will not trigger a javascript function. I have taken the return false out of the function and put it in the href but that doesn't work either.  I have put the same onclick code in a button and it triggers great.

HTML:

```
<a href='#' onclick='passvariables(" & aControl & "," & thissource &  ");'>Play</a>
```

Javascript:

```
function passvariables(aControl, thissource)
{
    var  yourAudio= new Audio();
    yourAudio.src = thissource;
    yourAudio.type = 'audio/wav';
    ctrl = document.getElementById(aControl);
    ctrl.onclick = function () 
    {
        // Update the Button
        var pause = ctrl.innerHTML === 'Pause';
        ctrl.innerHTML = pause ? 'Play' : 'Pause';

        // Update the Audio
        var method = pause ? 'pause' : 'play';
        yourAudio[method]();

        // Prevent Default Action
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any JavaScript error in the console? Also, " & aControl & " is not a valid HTML ID.

Comment: The aControl and YAudio are variables, as I have multiple instances because the links are based on records in a database.

Comment: No error, it just doesn't trigger the function.

Comment: I edited my answer, please have a look, should work now

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
window.passvariables = function(aControl, thissource) {
  // Your code
};
```

My guess if that your function is defined within another function (executed onload for instance). Hence "passvariables" is not defined in the "window" scope.

Comment: Please explain how this answers the question.

Comment: "passvariable" is probably defined within another function. (I just edited my answer to add this info)

Comment: I posted that comment originally because your answer was little more than code, with no explanation of how that code solved the given problem. It could be correct, easily, but it's better to teach people the general solution that to provide a copy/paste one-off. That general solution is what you e just added. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I saw you updated your questions that's good :)
First I recommend you to use the javascript library [jquery](http://www.jquery.com) which is easier to manipulate the DOM and you can easily find ressources and help on this site.

Here's what your code should look. I haven't tested it but it's a good overview of what this should be.

Put this in the `<head>` section of your HTML code

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //Assigning onClick function for every HTML tags having the css class "Play"
        $('.Play').click(function(){
            if($(this).html() == "Play"){
                //retrieving information about the audio
                var waveFile = $(this).attr("data-waveFile");
                var audioId = $(this).attr("data-audioId");
                //calling the startAudio function and assign the Audio object to myAudioObject
                var myAudioObject = startAudio(waveFile, audioId);
                if(myAudioObject){
                    //Audio started playing
                    $(this).html("Pause");
                }else{
                    alert("error while starting to play file");
                } 
            }else{
                var isPaused = pauseAudio(myAudioObject);
                if(isPaused){
                    //The pauseAudio function returned true so the audio is paused
                    $(this).html("Play");
                }else{
                    alert("error while pausing");
                }
            }
        });

        //Functions to manage audio Player
        function startAudio(waveFile, audioId){
        audioObject = document.getElementById("audio");
            audioObject.src = waveFile;
        audioObject.play();
        return true;
        }
        function pauseAudio(){
            //do whatever to pause
        audioObject = document.getElementById("audio");
        audioObject.pause();
            return true;
        }
    });
</script>
```

in the `<body>` section of your HTML code where you construct the table using database datas :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Song name</td>
        <td>Action</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><%=WaveFile%></td>
        <td><a href="#" class="Play" data-waveFile="<%=WaveFile%>" data-audioId="<%=AudioId%>">Play</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<audio id="audio"></audio>
```

Note the `<%=WaveFile%>` and `<%=AudioId%>` should be the values you get from the database in your loop

Comment: As mentioned above, the aControl and yAudio are variables, as I have multiple instances because the links are based on records in a database. And changing yourAudio[method](); to yourAudio(method); does nothing either.

Comment: Thank-you, you are correct, I do not need to use the return. I changed that hoping that could be the issue, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: You should update your question and explain what you try to achieve because your code is very messy..

Comment: Thank-you for the code yves.  It does the same thing mine does, no error message but will not trigger the function.

Comment: I stand corrected - it does pass the WaveFile and AudioID through to the function and does turn the word from Play to Pause and back to Play but the audio does not play.

Comment: I now have it playing, but it refuses to pause no matter what I do.

Comment: Of course it doesn't pause, the pause function is empty, you have to write the code to pause.. I guess it's something like audioObject.pause();

Comment: I know that and I have written code for the pause - but nothing works.                  function pauseAudio(audioObject){
   var thisObject = audioObject;
   thisObject.pause();
   return true;
          }                                                                                                                   I have also tried just using the variable without setting var = variable.  As well, I tried just using the audioID. When I check to make sure the object is being passed through, it shows that it is but the pause does nothing.

Comment: Yes my code was incorrect due to problem passing audio object through different functions. I read up about html audio element object and how it works. You have to create and <audio> tag element in the page and then you can control it via javascript. I tested with an mp3 file and I can play/pause.

Answer (score 0):

Just have `onclick` call `passvariables` without the `return` and have `passvariables` `return false`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank-you everyone for your help!  I finally got it working! Here is the code:

```
yAudio =  "'yourAudio" & thisline & "'"
aControl = "'audioControl" & thisline & "'"                                     
thissource = "'/WaveFiles/" & RS.Fields("AudioIssues") &"'"
R"<td width=12  class=allprint><a href='#' class='Play' data-waveFile=" & thissource & " data-audioId=" & aControl & ">Play</a></td>"

// Call and play audio via JavaScript
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var aElement = document.createElement('audio');
    $('.Play').click(function()         
    {
        if($(this).html() == "Play")
            {
                var waveFile = $(this).attr("data-waveFile");
                var audioID = $(this).attr("data-audioId");
                aElement.setAttribute('src', waveFile);
                aElement.load()
                aElement.addEventListener("load", function() 
                {
                     aElement.play();
                     $(this).html("Stop");
                     $(".duration span").html(aElement.duration);
                     $(".filename span").html(aElement.src);
                }, true);

                aElement.play();
                $(this).html("Stop");
            }
            else
            {   
                 var waveFile = $(this).attr("data-waveFile");
                 var audioID = $(this).attr("data-audioId");
                 aElement.setAttribute('src', waveFile);
                 aElement.pause();
                 $(this).html("Play");
            }
        });
});
```